# Why multithread slower loop in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 following code that use to calculate Pi :

Code 1 :

```
public class Main2 {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        System.out.println("Main 2");
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        double count = 1000000000d;
        double pi = 0;
        double denominator = 1;

        for (double x = 0; x <= count; x++) {       
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                pi = pi + (1 / denominator);
            } else {
                pi = pi - (1 / denominator);
            }
            denominator = denominator + 2;
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;

        System.out.println(pi*4 + " took " + time / 1000000 / 1e3);
    }

}
```

It took 35.255 seconds and result : 3.1415926545880506

Code 2:

```
public class LeibnizFormula implements Callable<Double> {

    private double pi;
    private double i;
    private double from;
    private double to;
    private double denominator;

    public double getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(double i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public double getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(double from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public double getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(double to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public double getPi() {
        return pi;
    }

    public void setPi(double pi) {
        this.pi = pi;
    }

    public double getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    public void setDenominator(double denominator) {
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    public LeibnizFormula(double from, double to, double denominator) {
        super();
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    @Override
    public Double call() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(i = from; i <= to; i++){
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                pi = pi + (1 / denominator);
            } else {
                pi = pi - (1 / denominator);
            }

            denominator += 2;
        }
        return pi;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Main 1");
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    double pi = 1d;
    double limit = 20000000; 
    double n = 1000000000d;
    double from =0;
    double to=0;
    double a = 0d;
    double denominator = 0;
    a = Math.round(n/limit);

    if (a == 0d) {
        a = 1;
    }

    for (double i=0d; i< a; i++) {
        if (i + 1d == a) {
            from = to + 1;
            to = (int)n;
        } else {
            to = to + limit;
            from = to - limit + 1d;
        }

        denominator = 2 * from + 1;
        LeibnizFormula leibniz = new LeibnizFormula(from, to, denominator);
        FutureTask f = new FutureTask(leibniz);
        Thread t = new Thread(f, "" + i);
        t.start();
        t.join();
        pi += (Double) f.get();
    }

    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println("took " + time / 1000000 / 1e3);
    System.out.println(pi * 4d);        
}
```

It took 36.062 and result : 3.141592654589748

I want to ask:

1.When I create and start the thread inside a loop, it still create many thread and process parallel or not ?

2.Sum the value that is return with large double number is exact or not. Do this  make the operation wrong so that why the wrong number is large ?

Comment: `t.start(); t.join();` For starters, you aren't processing in parallel.

Comment: @Radiodef: Thanks so much, I try to remove t.join(), but the performance is still stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are more than one reasons.

Firstly it is important to understand, that threading by itself have a significant overhead, so even well designed algorithms may perform worse then you would intuitivelly expect them (even worse then sequential alternatives) if there is not enough load, or the load balancing is not right.

Secondly although you use threads, you start your thread sequentaly inside a loop, an join them right after starting. This way you do not perform any real paralell calculations, and therefore you can not expect any performace gain :(

Comment: This is my mistake, but when i remove the join thread, the performance still stay the same.
Your mean I should start the thread out side the loop ?